# Why do most networking frameworks for iOS have a queue to manage requests?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

Why do most networking frameworks for iOS have a queue to manage requests?  What benefit does queueing requests brings?

For example, **AFNetworking** has an `NSOperationQueue` to manage its requests. Why is that queue needed?

Answer (score 3):

Networking requests are best done asynchronously. There are several reasons for this, such as unpredictable response time and possible network failures. So when you design an App that relies on network requests, it is best to design with this in mind. For example, if you need to fill a table, instead of doing it directly in a call, you would fill it as the data comes back in a call-back routine (or when your app discovers that the request is complete).

Asynchronous implies multiple tasks. Getting this right in your app design is hard. NSOperationQueues are a very good way to shield the app from some of these complexities. In particular, it provides a very natural way to make sure that tasks only get called when there data is ready - this is because an NSOperationQueue will serialize the tasks on the queue without you having to manage your own semaphores or other synchronization primitives.

Comment: Call-backs should have their own queue or share the same queue with requests?

Comment: If you want the calls to run in order, then they should share the same queue. Queus are sometimes called "FIFO" - first in, first out. So if you first add task A, then task B, into the same queue, task B will not start until task A is complete

Answer (score 0):

Not only it is important for asynchronous calls, but also you wouldn't want to hold state, would you? Maybe you want to have a sequence of calls - instead of waiting for response and then firing the next operation manually, you can fill the queue and let the manager dispatch it from there according to the response.

Other usage could be upload of multiple files - you wouldn't want to upload more than certain number at once right? What if you lose internet connection and you find yourself half way through all of them? That surely would upset your users. Rather you fill operation queue again and once one file has been uploaded, next one is automatically dispatched.

Lastly - if you use queue, in case of failure, you can have a queue watcher, that either re-dispatches failed query or deletes subsequent calls that would follow.

Overall it makes your networking component more robust and of course maintainable as well.